# How call requestLocationUpdates in thread?

Tags: android

I want get my location from a thread.
I code as:

```
LocationManager locationManager;
            GeoPoint p;
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria cri = new Criteria();
            String tower = locationManager.getBestProvider(cri, false);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(tower);
```

But How call `requestLocationUpdates`  update location?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have everything on the developer documentation: [Requesting Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: show exceiption if call LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() in thread.

Comment: What exception do you get? Post logcat

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: You need to create and register the listener on the UI thread. Google is your friend: https://www.google.fr/search?q=java.lang.RuntimeException%3A+Can't+create+handler+inside+thread+that+has+not+called+Looper.prepare